# Swift iOS UISlider stops working when placed in vertical stack view or assigned vertical alignment constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

Working on a timer app that uses a slider for user to choose a timer run duration in seconds. I have a label showing time remaining, a start button, and a stop button. Slider ideally would go below the time remaining label.

Codewise all is working fine - now on to appearance. Ideally I'd place all items (4 of them) in a vertical stack so everything fits, is centered, etc.

However, when I put the slider in the stack view, the slider will not function at all when running in the simulator. When I pull the slider back out of the stack view, runs fine.

I tried assigning a vertical constraint to the slider - center vertically in container - same problem.

I'm new to Swift/iOS app development but not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've seen no mention of this in the bit I've read so far.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

When I had a similar problem, it was because the slider was set to be the full width of the stack view and I believe that clips the frame. Setting a proportional width of 0.8 on the slider relative to the superview (i.e. the stack view) fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that!